# Unable to fetch rows from PostGresSQL table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm trying to fetch data from a table in the PostGreSQL database. I'm able to query the results using PostGreSQL but when I try to do so with Python using psycopg2 module, it doesn't return anything. The curse object returned is of type "None" and is non iterable.

Here's my code:

```
import psycopg2 as p
con = p.connect(database="Scheduling", user="postgres", password="test", host="127.0.0.1", 
port="5432")
cur = con.cursor()
df = cur.execute(''' SELECT * FROM  public."HOME" ''').fetchall()
print(type(df))
```

Here's the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/adi.jakka/PycharmProjects/Flask/TEST.PY", line 4, in 
    df = cur.execute(''' SELECT * FROM  public."HOME" ''').fetchall()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Is there any other way to get results from Postgres DB. I've been able to query results from Netezza and MS SQL Server with no issues before! When I run on Jupyter I get the following message: ** InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3e27ab41c921> in <module>
----> 1 cur.execute(''' SELECT * FROM public."HOME" ''')

InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block **

Comment: The cursor object isn't returned, you'll need to call execute and then fetchall.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
import psycopg2 as p
con = p.connect(database="Scheduling", user="postgres", password="test", host="127.0.0.1", 
port="5432")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(''' SELECT * FROM  public."HOME" ''')
df = cur.fetchall()
print(df)
```